# Reverse the rollsum function

Tags: r, zoo

The column `sum_last_3` contains the sum of the last 3 value of the column `x` using the function `zoo::rollsum`.

Is there a way to recreate the variable `x` only using the variable `sum_last_3` ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(x = c(2,3,5,6,8,1,0,2,3,5,1,9,5,3))
df$sum_last_3 <- rollsum(df$x, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right")
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to recreate the variable x only using the variable sum_last_3 ?"* No, you need the first element of `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation is not invertible; however, if instead of filling the first two elements of the result with NA we use `partial=TRUE` to get partial sums then it is.  The `rollapplyr` lines below are the same as the `rollsum` in the question except we use partial sums for the first two elements.  M is the matrix representation of that operation which we obtain by running the operation against the identity matrix.  At the end we invert M and multiply that by df$sum_last_3 to recover the original input.

```
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(x = c(2,3,5,6,8,1,0,2,3,5,1,9,5,3))
df$sum_last_3 <- rollapplyr(df$x, 3, sum, partial = TRUE) 

M <- rollapplyr(diag(nrow(df)), 3, sum, partial = TRUE)
solve(M, df$sum_last_3)
## [1] 2 3 5 6 8 1 0 2 3 5 1 9 5 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, you won't have an exactly same solution of `x` given `sum_last_3`, and you can view it from the matrix perspective.

---

For simplification, `x` and `y` are input and output, respectively

```
x <- df$x
y <- na.omit(df$sum_last_3)
```

and there is a matrix representation `m` for the `rollsum` process such that `y = m %*% x`, where `m` can be written as

```
> m <- matrix(0, length(x) - 2, length(x))
> m <- replace(m, col(m) - row(m) >= 0 & col(m) - row(m) <= 2, 1)

> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
 [2,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
 [3,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0     0     0     0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1     0     0     0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1     0     0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     1     1     0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     1     1
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     1
      [,14]
 [1,]     0
 [2,]     0
 [3,]     0
 [4,]     0
 [5,]     0
 [6,]     0
 [7,]     0
 [8,]     0
 [9,]     0
[10,]     0
[11,]     0
[12,]     1
```

and we can check that

```
> m %*% x - y
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    0
 [4,]    0
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    0
 [7,]    0
 [8,]    0
 [9,]    0
[10,]    0
[11,]    0
[12,]    0
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 1 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

However, we should be aware that `m` is a singular matrix, such that the length of resulting `y` is shorter than `x`. For this linear system, we can use `MASS::ginv` to solve `xhat`, but which is not exactly the same as `x`

```
> (xhat <- MASS::ginv(m) %*% y)
             [,1]
 [1,]  1.93846154
 [2,]  3.13846154
 [3,]  4.92307692
 [4,]  5.93846154
 [5,]  8.13846154
 [6,]  0.92307692
 [7,] -0.06153846
 [8,]  2.13846154
 [9,]  2.92307692
[10,]  4.93846154
[11,]  1.13846154
[12,]  8.92307692
[13,]  4.93846154
[14,]  3.13846154
```